# How to append one string _base64image to another one string _base64image2

Tags: c#, blazor

I need to save a screenshot to an image file on disk and I use html2canvas.js to retrieve the screen portion but due to the size of the file (80K) and Blazor 32K R-signal limitation I have to do it in chunks, as recommended by Microsoft. I am doing that, but what I don't know is how to concatenate them back into one file. I have tried some examples from this site. first I tried to concatenate the strings,then   the byte[] but at no avail.

```
async Task SaveScreenShotToFile()
{
    string _divScreenShot1 = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("GetDivScreenShot", "divRaHeader");
    string _divScreenShot2 = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("GetDivScreenShot", "divRaFooter");

    if (_divScreenShot1 != null)
    {
        var filepath = @"C:\VS2022\AppMain\wwwroot\Image.jpg";
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {
                string convert = _divScreenShot1.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", String.Empty);
                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(convert);

                string convert2 = _divScreenShot2.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", String.Empty);
                byte[] data2 = Convert.FromBase64String(convert);

                byte[] data3 = data.Concat(data2).ToArray();

                bw.Write(data3);

                bw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

script
function GetDivScreenShot(divId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById(divId), document.body, { allowTaint: true, useCors: true },
            { background: "#00FFFFFF" }).then(canvas => {
                resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', .5))
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: You cannot just concatenate files. You need to unpack the jpeg images and then write the pixels to your output image, either using System.Drawing.Graphics, or if you are comfortable with manipulating pixel buffers, by directly copying pixels from one chunk to the correct place in the output. But it really depends on how you chunked the image in the first place.

Comment: @JonasH I added 2 extra divs and read each one using "canvas.toDataURL(')" Is there an example for the former solution on your comment ? I am not familiar with the latter.

Comment: Start by describing, or better yet, post example code,  how you are "chunking" your data. If you are doing it on the file level your current idea should work, but then you should not label the data as images.

Comment: @JonasH I updated the post with adt'l code.  In the end, each div generates an image file size around 20k  and if I add both the resulting file size is 40k but only the first image shows up.

Answer (score 0):

The above code uses the BinaryWriter which will serialize the byte array, including type information to the file. As far as I can tell you can simply write the raw byte array from the decoded base64 string directly to the FileStream by using `fs.Write( byte );`.